# Toggle GameObject/component active state on key press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
    {
        ObjectOne.SetActive(true)
        Debug.Log("set");
    } 

    Debug.Log ("Update is called");
}
```

I want to toggle `SetActive` when I press Tab again and true when I press it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to toggle activation and de-activation of the GameObject each time the tab key is pressed, get the current state with `ObjectOne.activeSelf`, when the tab key is pressed. Flip that with `!` then pass that flipped value to the `SetActive` function.

```
public GameObject ObjectOne;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
    {
        //Get current State
        bool currentState = ObjectOne.activeSelf;

        //Flip it
        currentState = !currentState;

        //Set the current State to the flipped value
        ObjectOne.SetActive(currentState);
    }
}
```

This can also be done in one line of code:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        ObjectOne.SetActive(!ObjectOne.activeSelf);
}
```

---

If this is a component then use [`Behaviour.enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) instead. The whole toggling thing is still the-same. It is better to cache the component instead of getting it in the `Update` function but I won't in the example below for the case of simplicity.

```
public GameObject ObjectOne;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
    {
        Renderer rdr = ObjectOne.GetComponent<Renderer>();

        //Get current State
        bool currentState = rdr.enabled;

        //Flip it
        currentState = !currentState;

        //Set the current State to the flipped value
        rdr.enabled = currentState;
    }
}
```